# Django - django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_session

Tags: django

I am trying to use AbstractUser in django. I made migrations and migrated and everything goes fine but then i tried to login using admin and i got the Following Error-

no such table: django_session
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:
no such table: django_session

Can anyone help how should i fix this?

I have also added AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py

Comment: Remove migrations in all apps from migration.py except the `_init_.py` and then re migrate

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the issue was i just making migrations only for my django app not for  whole project so i fixed that and then everything is working fine.